# How to go to the variable's stored location directly in decompiler mode of IDA?

Tags: ida

When i'm debugging a code in decompiler mode, one problem i face is that when i double click on a variable, it goes to "stack locations" instead of the actual address that the variable/structure is stored :

```
-0000002C KeyHandle dd ?                          ; offset
-00000028 RegistryPath LSA_UNICODE_STRING ?
-00000020 var_20 dd ?
-0000001C var_1C dd ?
-00000018 var_18 dd ?
-00000014 var_14 dd ?
-00000010 var_10 dd ?
-0000000C var_C dd ?
-00000008 var_8 dd ?
```

And clicking on the variable names in above tab doesn't go to the address either.

also I'm not sure why but everytime, all the values of this place are "?", which is not really useful, so in order for me to go to actually go to the address this variable is stored, i have to point my mouse on it, find its address, then write it in cntrl+g to go there.

it would be a lot better if i could just click on the variable and it went to the address that this variable is stored, is there any way i can do this?